# function definition with function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to know if defining a function within a function is a good practice in JavaScript.

Here is an example:

```
module.exports = function() {
  function foo() {
    // do something
  }

  ...
  foo()
  ...
}
```

To me, this looks very strange. But I see this often when reading open source projects.

Is it better to define `foo` outside of the scope of `module.exports` in the above example? Why and why not?

Comment: inside a module, it doesn't really matter where you define it, but if exports is expensive to execute, it might make more sense to use closure to pull the function in from inside so as to not re-init that supporting functionality.

Comment: Please explain how I can improve this question when downvoting. I know It might be a nooby question, but I was genuinely curious.

Comment: @MikeC—don't expect down voters to explain their vote, not everyone has good manners. One up is worth 5 down so not difficult to overcome. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript a function can be defined at the global scope or in any function scope.  As a general good design practice, you want to limit the scope of a function to only that scope that needs to call it.  That means that often you define locally used functions within other functions.

In addition, function declarations declared within another function scope can also access all the other variables within that scope which can be extremely useful.

This serves a number of general benefits:

1. It keeps the function private to only the scope that needs to use it (it cannot be called from outside the scope in which it is defined unless a reference is explicitly passed to some other function or variable outside the scope).
2. It keeps you from polluting a top level scope with zillions of named functions, some of which might even have conflicting names in a very large project.  In node modules, this is not so much the case because a node module is already a limited scope.
3. It allows a function to have access to the other variables within that scope.

That was the "general" discussion.  Now, within a node module, the code in the module is already within a private scope so it is not as important to declare a function within the exports function as you've done, but I generally follow a practice of declaring a function only in the scope in which it will be used.

In addition, many functions can be declared inline and anonymously and don't even need a name.

In your specific example:

```
module.exports = function() {

  var cntr = 0;

  function foo() {
    // do something
  }

  ...
  foo()
  ...
}
```

It really depends upon what you're using `foo` for.  If you are never using it in any other scope, then I would favor declaring it within that scope as you've done.

If you need or want to access other variables within that scope such as the `cntr` variable I've shown, then it must be declared within the scope.

Comment: The same person that down voted my post, did the same for your post. Since, yours is a far more detailed answer, I will remove mine (+1 from me).

Comment: @dandavis I had exactly the same question...:(

Comment: just to clarify my first comment, if a thing like `var cntr = 0;` above were expensive to init, then it might make sense to move it out of the exports function, since that gets executed each time require() is used on the module...

Comment: @dandavis - actually, it doesn't get called on just the `require()`.  The function shown here would only get called if they actually loaded it with `require()` and then called the module constructor explicitly as in `var myModule = require('moduleName');   myModule();`.  But, to your point, variables should be declared in the appropriate scope so something in the module constructor will get reinitialized each time the module constructor is called (which is sometimes what you want and sometimes not).

Comment: Downvoter, please explain so I can address whatever concern you apparently had.

Comment: fair enough, but what's the point of requiring a function that doesn't get used? to be even more clear: assuming it gets used, assuming it's expensive, assuming it can be "stale", and assuming it's required/init'd 1+ times, then moving a depend above the exports-assigned function can save time instantiating.

Comment: @dandavis - the module can have other methods or properties that are accessed.  One does not always have to call the module constructor.  The location of a variable like `cntr` is not about saving time - it's about whether it is supposed to be initialized only once when the module is first loaded or whether it's supposed to be initialized each time the constructor is called.  Those are different use cases for different types of variables and what type of variable it is should drive where it is declared.

Comment: i was trying to give one example of when not to inner-declare, but given the elaborate qualifications, it stand to reason that most of the time, you probably want to declare inside as shown ;)